# Objective-C Dictionary keys sorting in descending order

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsdictionary

I have an unordered dictionary like this:

```
@{ @"20101R" : @"value1", 
   @"20102R" : @"value2", 
   @"20131R" : @"value3", 
   @"20111R" : @"value4", 
   @"20122R" : @"value5" }
```

Each key represents **Year** and either **1R** or **2R**.

For UITableView, I wish to put 'keys' as title and 'values' as subtitle like this:

from **latest** key value -> **oldest** key value

```
title : 20131R
subtitle : value3

title : 20122R
subtitle : value5

title : 20111R
subtitle : value4

title : 20102R
subtitle : value2

title : 20101R
subtitle : value1
```

Can you help me sort this number-like string in descending order?
What is the simplest way to do this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be ordered.  Keep a separate array which holds the dictionary keys, in the order you want them displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull out the keys with

```
NSArray *keysArray = [dictionary allKeys];
```

Then sort the array:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [keysArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString*  _Nonnull obj1, NSString*  _Nonnull obj2) {
    return obj1 < obj2;
}];
```

Comment: How is that descending?  You either need to reverse the resulting array or use NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: @dgatwood Right you are! I've updated the sort method!

Comment: I don't think you can safely use comparison operators on Objective-C object pointers that way.  You could, however, use `-[obj1 compare:obj2]`.  (Note the negative, to swap `NSOrderedAscending` and `NSOrderedDescending`.)